# django_tenants not resolving subdomains

Tags: django, django-tenants

I have setup and installed django_tenants with the standard settings and middleware from the [documentation](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) and watched Tom's Youtube video.

```
'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware'
```

and the option

```
SHOW_PUBLIC_IF_NO_TENANT_FOUND = True
```

The PostgresSQL scheme segregation is working perfectly and I have created a demo tenant with host demo.localhost

[image]

[image]

I am running the server locally with

```
python3 manage.py runserver localhost:8000
```

in my browser, localhost:8000 works perfectly however the subdomain, demo.localhost:8000 is never resolved and I see no request in the terminal.

Is there something I am missing or logs I can check to try and troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a day of troubleshooting, the problems seems to be with Safari. Using Edge I am able to browse to a subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is not a domain, it just refer to your computer. So It won't resolve any subdomain.

You could try it to add a custom domain to the `/etc/hosts` file:

`127.0.0.1 mycustomdomain.com subdomain.mycustomdomain.com`

And try again, but replace localhost with your new domain in the configurations.